# How to set id in Jetpack Compose for Appium and UIAutomator (Xpath issue)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, xpath, appium-android, android-uiautomator

I am using Jetpack Compose and Appium with UIAutomator. I would like to set a unique `id` for the Composables instead of showing the Xpath because of:
*Using XPath locators is not recommended and can lead to fragile tests. Ask your development team to provide unique accessibility locators instead*.

Inside Android Studio under my Composable I have added:

```
Row(
  modifier = Modifier.semantics { testTagsAsResourceId = true }
    ...
    ) {
       Text(
         modifier = Modifier.semantics { testTag = "testTag" },
```

Now in Appium I can see that the `resource-id` = testTag, but the `id` is still showing the Xpath.

According to [this](https://juliensalvi.medium.com/ui-tests-with-jetpack-compose-and-appium-x-uiautomator-5d276fb655aa) article I should be able to set the `id` to the same as `resource-id` by using `@AndroidFindBy` and some class `UiSelector`  but I do not understand how - should I add this annotation inside my Composable?

I read about a solution [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/discussions/16329) but Espresso is not an option for me, unfortunately.

I also tried using:

```
modifier = Modifier.semantics { this.contentDescription = "testTag" },
```

And this actually changed the Xpath, but still it showed the warning above.

This is how I would like to have it (where id and resource-id has the same value): [image from article](https://miro.medium.com/max/4800/1*pfhzyrGjX2OUh_rgxoQvbA.webp)

Comment: Modifier.semantics { this.contentDescription = "testTag" } seems to work if we set driver as driver.find_element(by = AppiumBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, value="testTag")